# c_src\bcrypt_nif.c(94) : error C2275: 'ERL_NIF_TERM' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, erlang, elixir, bcrypt

I was wondering if anyone has seen this error before and if so what can be done about it.

```
C:\workspace\myproj>iex -S mix phx.server
==> bcrypt_elixir

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        del /Q /F priv
        erl -eval "io:format(\"~s~n\", [lists:concat([\"ERTS_INCLUDE_PATH=\", code:root_dir(), \"/erts-\", erlang:system_info(version), \"/include\"])])" -s init stop -noshell > Makefile.auto.win
        nmake /                   /F Makefile.win priv\bcrypt_nif.dll

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        if NOT EXIST "priv" mkdir "priv"
        cl /O2 /EHsc /I"c_src /std:c11" /I"c:/Program Files/erl10.7/erts-10.7/include" /LD /MD /Fepriv\bcrypt_nif.dll  c_src\bcrypt_nif.c c_src\blowfish.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

bcrypt_nif.c
c_src\bcrypt_nif.c(94) : error C2275: 'ERL_NIF_TERM' : illegal use of this type as an expression
        c:/Program Files/erl10.7/erts-10.7/include\erl_nif.h(100) : see declaration of 'ERL_NIF_TERM'
c_src\bcrypt_nif.c(94) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'output'
c_src\bcrypt_nif.c(94) : error C2065: 'output' : undeclared identifier
c_src\bcrypt_nif.c(95) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
c_src\bcrypt_nif.c(97) : error C2065: 'output_data' : undeclared identifier
c_src\bcrypt_nif.c(99) : error C2065: 'output' : undeclared identifier
c_src\bcrypt_nif.c(377) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'volatile'
c_src\bcrypt_nif.c(379) : error C2065: 'ptr' : undeclared identifier
c_src\bcrypt_nif.c(379) : error C2100: illegal indirection
c_src\bcrypt_nif.c(379) : error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
blowfish.c
Generating Code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
could not compile dependency :bcrypt_elixir, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile bcrypt_elixir", update it with "mix deps.update bcrypt_elixir" or clean it with "mix deps.clean bcrypt_elixir"
==> orcasite
** (Mix) Could not compile with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" (exit status: 2).
One option is to install a recent version of
[Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)
either manually or using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) -
`choco install VisualCppBuildTools`.

After installing Visual C++ Build Tools, look in the "Program Files (x86)"
directory and search for "Microsoft Visual Studio". Note down the full path
of the folder with the highest version number. Open the "run" command and
type in the following command (make sure that the path and version number
are correct):

    cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64

This should open up a command prompt with the necessary environment variables
set, and from which you will be able to run the "mix compile", "mix deps.compile",
and "mix test" commands.
```

I tried changing the compiler's C version in the bcrypt Makefile.in but the result was the same.

**Environment**:

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Erlang: 10.7

Elixir: 1.10.3

Microsoft C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version: 16.00.30319.01 for x64

bcrypt_elixir:  2.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the C compiler ends up not understanding code following the C99 standard; in particular it doesn't permit variable declarations after the first statement in a function.

Since bcrypt_elixir has a `Makefile.win` file, suggesting that it has compiled successfully on Windows before, I don't quite understand why this is happening, but in any case you should be able to fix this by modifying `bcrypt_nif.c`, changing this:

```c
static ERL_NIF_TERM bcrypt_gensalt_nif(ErlNifEnv *env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
{
    ErlNifBinary csalt;
    unsigned int log_rounds, minor;

    if (argc != 3 || !enif_inspect_binary(env, argv[0], &csalt) ||
            csalt.size != BCRYPT_MAXSALT ||
            !enif_get_uint(env, argv[1], &log_rounds) ||
            !enif_get_uint(env, argv[2], &minor))
        return enif_make_badarg(env);

    ERL_NIF_TERM output;
    unsigned char *output_data = enif_make_new_binary(env, BCRYPT_SALTSPACE, &output);

    bcrypt_initsalt(log_rounds, (uint8_t *)csalt.data, (char *)output_data, (uint8_t)minor);

    return output;
}
```

to this:

```c
static ERL_NIF_TERM bcrypt_gensalt_nif(ErlNifEnv *env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
{
    ErlNifBinary csalt;
    unsigned int log_rounds, minor;
    /* added these two lines */
    ERL_NIF_TERM output;
    unsigned char *output_data;

    if (argc != 3 || !enif_inspect_binary(env, argv[0], &csalt) ||
            csalt.size != BCRYPT_MAXSALT ||
            !enif_get_uint(env, argv[1], &log_rounds) ||
            !enif_get_uint(env, argv[2], &minor))
        return enif_make_badarg(env);

    /* removed one line, and modified this line: */
    output_data = enif_make_new_binary(env, BCRYPT_SALTSPACE, &output);

    bcrypt_initsalt(log_rounds, (uint8_t *)csalt.data, (char *)output_data, (uint8_t)minor);

    return output;
}
```

There might be other places where you need to do similar changes.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this works. After moving variable declarations to the top of the methods and also replacing snprintf with _snprintf uniformly throughout the file the error disappeared.